# STEAM - How to get dota 2 player with personaname, loccountrycode and avatar url from steam account

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api

I want to get item with personaname, loccountrycode and avatar from dota 2 web api.
Currently I am just getting name and image. Please provide me some reference with documentation. I want the response like -

```
{
"tracked_until": "string",
"solo_competitive_rank": "string",
"competitive_rank": "string",
"rank_tier": 0,
"leaderboard_rank": 0,
"mmr_estimate": {
"estimate": 0,
"stdDev": 0,
"n": 0
},
"profile": {
"account_id": 0,
"personaname": "string",
"name": "string",
"cheese": 0,
"steamid": "string",
"avatar": "string",
"avatarmedium": "string",
"avatarfull": "string",
"profileurl": "string",
"last_login": "string",
"loccountrycode": "string"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reference to the SteamWebAPI for DOTA 2: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/index.php?title=WebAPI&redirect=no#Dota_2